# SwiftUI Image not updating its URL when View loads

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-location, appdelegate, combine

I have a global object of class UserLocation which is initialized in `AppDelegate.swift`. I'm getting current location of user and changing an image inside my SwiftUI view based on current location of user. 
Here is `UserLocation` class:

```
class UserLocation: ObservableObject {
      var userCurrentState: StateEnum = .None 
// StateEnum is an enum to store state areas like west, east and its default value is .None
}
```

Inside my `CoreLocation` method, after some calculation I'm setting the `userCurrentState` of global `userLocation` object

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {

        * some calculations * 
        userLocation.userCurrentState = .West
    }
```

`StateEnum` has a method `getStateImage` that returns a `String` which is the name of an image inside my app's `xcassets` so here is how I am using it inside my SwiftUI view:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var locationOfUser: UserLocation 
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(locationOfUser.userCurrentState.getStateImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .leading)
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
           static var previews: some View {
                  ContentView().environmentObject(userLocation)
           }
    }
```

The problem is when I start the app, the image against the "None" state shows up and does not change. I am changing the image based on current location, as soon as user enters in a new area and user's state gets changed the image changes but I am not getting the expected behavior. However if I put a 2 msec interval before initializing my view then the images keeps changing based on current location. It just doesn't change when I start the application and gets the image against None enum. What I observe is the micro seconds difference between view initialization and `CoreLocation` getting current location. Which gets resolved with `Timer` but I do not want to use `Timer`or any other hack.

Comment: Did you mark your `userCurrentState` with `@Published` property wrapper? I don't see that. To be able to get the latest value every time your property changes, you need a publisher. And that's what the simple `@Published` property wrapper for.

Comment: It still doesn’t work

Comment: Are you receiving the updates on main thread.  If not, update the values in main thread

Comment: I’m receiving on main thread.

Comment: How did you implement & initialize `CLLocationManagerDelegate` conforming object?

Comment: It’s inside AppDelegate. Location updates are fine, I’m getting everything done in that department just fine.